# expanding logorithms

Tags: algebra-precalculus

**The problem:**
Use the properties of logarithms to expand each expression completely. That is, write each expression in terms of simpler logarithms of the form $a \log_b(\text{variable})$. Assume that all variables denote positive numbers.
[image]

**My work:**

$\log_{10}(\sqrt{(s-a)(s-b)})^\frac{1}{2}$

$\frac{1}{2}\log_{10}[(s-a)(s-b)]$

$\frac{1}{2}\log_{10}[s^2-bs-as+ab]$

*The computer did not accept the above as the correct answer*

$1\log_{10}(s^2)-\frac{1}{2}\log_{10}(bs)-\frac{1}{2}\log_{10}(as)+\frac{1}{2}\log_{10}(ab)$

*That was also not accepted*

I'm sure I am wrong and not the computer, lol.

EDIT:

I checked my work with mathway.com, and it came up with the same answer I got on paper except on paper I wrote it as (sb) and mathway got (bs)

[image]

Comment: $\frac{1}{2}\log_{10}(s^2-as-bs+ab)$ is technically correct, but not what is intended. The next one is just wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\log_{10}[(s-a)(s-b)]^\frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2}\log_{10}(s-a) + \frac{1}{2}\log_{10}(s-b)
$$

But $\log_{10}(s^2-bs-as+ab)$ is not the same as $\log_{10}(s^2)-\log_{10}(bs)-\log_{10}(as)+\log_{10}(ab)$.

Comment: Please look at my edit on the original post to check out what I did to check my answer. And is it $\frac{1}{2}log_{10}(s-a) + \frac{1}{2}log_{10}(s-b)$? Remember there was a square root.

Comment: @GeekyDewd : You had $\frac12\log_{10}[(s-a)(s-b)]$.  If it is the case that $\log_{10}[(s-a)(s-b)]=\log_{10}(s-a)+\log_{10}(s-b)$, then it is the case that $\frac12\log_{10}[(s-a)(s-b)]=\frac12\log_{10}(s-a)+\frac12\log_{10}(s-b)$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: So they are the same?

Comment: @GeekyDewd : $\frac12\log_{10}[(s-a(s-b)]$ is not the same as $\log_{10}[(s-a(s-b)]$, but the statement that $\log_{10}[(s-a)(s-b)]=\log_{10}(s-a)+\log_{10}(s-b)$ is the same as the statement that $\frac12\log_{10}[(s-a)(s-b)]=\frac12\log_{10}(s-a)+\frac12\log_{10}(s-b)$. ${}\qquad{}$